# unable to find project exploded aar

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

We have simple composite gradle build with android project and a library project.  We are getting the following error from the build

```
> Task :kds-android-studio:lintAnalyzeDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kds-android-studio:lintAnalyzeDebug'.
> unable to find project exploded aar for /Users/dean/workspace/tray/monorepo/android/libraries/tray-lib-android-studio :
```

In the build file, we have this line to pull in the artifact(per composite builds)

```
implementation 'com.tray.android.lib:tray-lib-android-studio'
```

In the settings.gradle file, we have this(per composite builds)

```
includeBuild '../../libraries/tray-lib-android-studio'
```

I have no idea what an aar file is.  Any direction on debugging this further would be great?  (I am mostly guessing right now and google doesn't seem to have any results on lintAnalyzeDebug and "unable to find project exploded aar".

I see an aar file fro debug and release in the tray-lib-android-studio project.  Where is the main gradle project searching for 'exploded aar' and I wonder if I can just hack a target before the one that fails to explode the library aar in a good location to get this passing?

Comment: can you add the code of your gradle build and settings gradle file.

Comment: and about the information of the `.arr` file, see this article from android documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library#:~:text=AAR%20files%20can%20contain%20Android,app%20module's%20C%2FC%2B%2B%20code.

Comment: @RohitBhati I posted a trim down version with a brand new project here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73415617/composite-builds-broken-on-android-or-did-i-do-this-wrong instead thinking I could simplify the issue but then got stuck though it is a completely different error.  If I can solve that one first, I may be able to work on this one myself or repost more detail with a simpler project by comparing the two projects.

Comment: @RohitBhati regarding your other post, I found a really good post on creating a 'true library' not tied to 1 android app.  you just create android app and modify com.android.application plugin to com.android.library so you have an independent library with no weird shell project.

Comment: @DeanHiller were you able to solve this issue? Can you provide the solution if you found any?